# AutoArchive feature not working in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, autoarchive

I have Office 2010 Professional Plus 2010 (14.0.7145.5000 32-bit) SP2 installed on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Edition.

AutoArchive feature doesn't seem to be working. I have an Exchange account configured and this is my folder structure -

```
Inbox
  /Follow-up
  /Hold
  /Archive
Sent Items
Deleted Items
```

I need to archive the items in the Inbox/Archive and Sent Items folders. I right-clicked on both of them individually, switched to AutoArchive tab and applied these settings -

```
Archive this folder using these settings
Clean out items older than 7 days
Move items to <path/to/custom/pst/file>
```

The parent "Inbox" folder though has "Do not archive items in this folder" selected as I only want the sub-folder "Inbox/Archive" to be auto-archived.

I'm also using the following Registry key to archive based on Received time and not Modified time:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Preferences
Value name: ArchiveIgnoreLastModifiedTime
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1
```

I then went to File > Cleanup Tools > Archive, selected "Archive all folders according to their AutoArchive Settings" and clicked OK.

Nothing happens. I see the message "Archiving" in the status bar but the messages are still in the Inbox/Archive and Sent Items folders.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem -- I've got AutoArchive setup on my Inbox and each of my subfolders, but nothing ever gets archived -- EVEN if I attempt to manually force the Archive using the "Archive all folders according to their AutoArchive settings" option. Did you ever find a solution? (I'm using Outlook 2013 -- I also am using a custom archive PST, located on a network drive).